# Submit input after 7 characters

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have a web-app using a single input form that is filled via a barcode scanner. I have noticed on barcodes over 6 characters the barcode scanner prematurely submits, causing the form to submit with the incorrect data. I have managed to prevent the barcode scanner from returning (can be done via programming, but we go through barcode scanners, so I'd rather it be plug and play for employee's). my question is - How can make sure the form isn't submitted until the full 7 characters are entered? Any recommendations appreciated.

here is my form

```
<form action="PupListMobile.php" id="my_form" method="get">
     <label for="text-1"></label>
     <input type="text" autofocus name="sID" id="sID" value="" id="my_button" placeholder="CLICK TO SCAN:">
     <input type="hidden" name="lane" value="1" />
     <input id="subHere"type="submit" value="Submit"  />

</form>
```

Here is my J Query

```
$('#sID').keyup(function(){
    if(this.value.length ==7){
    $('#subHere').click();
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: serverside http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php

Comment: Not sure where to go from there.

Comment: `if (strlen($string)>=7)`

Comment: same thing would probably apply to what you have in js now `if(this.value.length >=7)`

Comment: I'm using JS because I want to check the submit before it is submitted. with PHP it would require it to be submitted and checked correct?

Comment: js can always be disabled by the user; use both methods; client and serverside.

Comment: if I misinterpreted the question, then change `if (strlen($string)>=7)` to `if (strlen($string)<=7)` same logic for js

Comment: That makes sense - thank you. Do you know why my code wont auto submit the form after 7 characters?

Comment: I work mostly serverside, sorry can't help you with the auto/iphone stuff.

Comment: no problem, i appreciate you trying.

Comment: glad to have helped. You did tag as php though and thought the question was solved. Yet, you added a few more questions in comments which IMHO, should have been part of the question from the beginning.

Comment: It is the same question - just reworded, the question wasn't solved.

Comment: so why the php tag?

Answer (score 1):

Form:

```
<form action="PupListMobile.php" id="my_form" method="get">
 <label for="text-1"></label>
 <input type="text" autofocus name="sID" id="sID" value="" placeholder="CLICK TO SCAN:">
 <input type="hidden" name="lane" value="1" />
 <input id="subHere"type="submit" value="Submit"  />

</form>
```

Not sure why it wouldn't work on Iphone/pad.

Javascript:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#my_form').submit(function(event) {
            if ($('#sID').val().length < 7) {
                event.preventDefault();
                // maybe display message to user
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: js can always be disabled. If that ever happens, then they can pass anything they want in there.

Comment: Do you know why that wouldn't be working on an iphone or Ipad?

Comment: What browser are you using?